# Why Postgres EXPLAIN ANALYSE report huge performance difference compare to real query execution

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-execution-plan

I have been tasked with rewriting some low performance sql in our system for which I have this query

```
select
    "aggtable".id as t_id,
    count(joined.packages)::integer as t_package_count,
    sum(coalesce((joined.packages ->> 'weight'::text)::double precision, 0::double precision)) as t_total_weight
from
    "aggtable"
join (
    select
        "unnested".myid, json_array_elements("jsontable".jsondata) as packages
    from
        (
        select
            distinct unnest("tounnest".arrayofid) as myid
        from
            "aggtable" "tounnest") "unnested"
    join "jsontable" on
        "jsontable".id = "unnested".myid) joined on
    joined.myid = any("aggtable".arrayofid)
group by
    "aggtable".id
```

The EXPLAN ANALYSE result is

```
        Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 611kB
        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=30917.16..31333627.69 rows=27270 width=69) (actual time=4.028..2054.470 rows=3658 loops=1)
              Join Filter: ((unnest(tounnest.arrayofid)) = ANY (aggtable.arrayofid))
              Rows Removed by Join Filter: 9055436
              ->  ProjectSet  (cost=30917.16..36645.61 rows=459000 width=48) (actual time=3.258..13.846 rows=3322 loops=1)
                    ->  Hash Join  (cost=30917.16..34316.18 rows=4590 width=55) (actual time=3.246..7.079 rows=1661 loops=1)
                          Hash Cond: ((unnest(tounnest.arrayofid)) = jsontable.id)
                          ->  Unique  (cost=30726.88..32090.38 rows=144700 width=16) (actual time=1.901..3.720 rows=1664 loops=1)
                                ->  Sort  (cost=30726.88..31408.63 rows=272700 width=16) (actual time=1.900..2.711 rows=1845 loops=1)
                                      Sort Key: (unnest(tounnest.arrayofid))
                                      Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 135kB
                                      ->  ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..1444.22 rows=272700 width=16) (actual time=0.011..1.110 rows=1845 loops=1)
                                            ->  Seq Scan on aggtable tounnest  (cost=0.00..60.27 rows=2727 width=30) (actual time=0.007..0.311 rows=2727 loops=1)
                          ->  Hash  (cost=132.90..132.90 rows=4590 width=55) (actual time=1.328..1.329 rows=4590 loops=1)
                                Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 454kB
                                ->  Seq Scan on jsontable  (cost=0.00..132.90 rows=4590 width=55) (actual time=0.006..0.497 rows=4590 loops=1)
              ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..73.91 rows=2727 width=67) (actual time=0.000..0.189 rows=2727 loops=3322)
                    ->  Seq Scan on aggtable  (cost=0.00..60.27 rows=2727 width=67) (actual time=0.012..0.317 rows=2727 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.160 ms
Execution Time: 2065.268 ms
```

I tried to rewrite this query from scratch to profile performance and to understand the original intention

```
select 
    joined.joinid,
    count(joined.packages)::integer as t_package_count,
    sum(coalesce((joined.packages ->> 'weight'::text)::double precision, 0::double precision)) as t_total_weight
from 
(
select
    joinid ,
    json_array_elements(jsondata) as packages
from
    ( (
    select
        distinct unnest(at2.arrayofid) as joinid, at2.id as rootid
    from
        aggtable at2) unnested
join jsontable jt on
    jt.id = unnested.joinid)) joined
    group by joined.joinid
```

For which the EXPLAIN ANALYSE return

```
HashAggregate  (cost=873570.28..873572.78 rows=200 width=28) (actual time=18.379..18.741 rows=1661 loops=1)
  Group Key: (unnest(at2.arrayofid))
  ->  ProjectSet  (cost=44903.16..191820.28 rows=27270000 width=48) (actual time=3.019..14.684 rows=3658 loops=1)
        ->  Hash Join  (cost=44903.16..53425.03 rows=272700 width=55) (actual time=3.010..4.999 rows=1829 loops=1)
              Hash Cond: ((unnest(at2.arrayofid)) = jt.id)
              ->  Unique  (cost=44712.88..46758.13 rows=272700 width=53) (actual time=1.825..2.781 rows=1845 loops=1)
                    ->  Sort  (cost=44712.88..45394.63 rows=272700 width=53) (actual time=1.824..2.135 rows=1845 loops=1)
                          Sort Key: (unnest(at2.arrayofid)), at2.id
                          Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 308kB
                          ->  ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..1444.22 rows=272700 width=53) (actual time=0.009..1.164 rows=1845 loops=1)
                                ->  Seq Scan on aggtable at2  (cost=0.00..60.27 rows=2727 width=67) (actual time=0.005..0.311 rows=2727 loops=1)
              ->  Hash  (cost=132.90..132.90 rows=4590 width=55) (actual time=1.169..1.169 rows=4590 loops=1)
                    Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 454kB
                    ->  Seq Scan on jsontable jt  (cost=0.00..132.90 rows=4590 width=55) (actual time=0.007..0.462 rows=4590 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.144 ms
Execution Time: 18.889 ms
```

I see a huge difference in the query performance (20ms to 2000ms), as evaluated by postgres. Howver, the real query performance is no where near that difference **( the fast one is about 500ms and the slow one is about 1s )**

My question

1/ Is that normal that EXPLAIN produce drastic difference in performance but not so much in real life?

2/ Is the second - optimized query correct? what did the first query do wrong?

I suppy also the credential to a sample database so that everyone can try the queries out

postgres://birylwwg:X6EM3Al9Jhqzz0w6EaSSx79pa4aXRBZq@arjuna.db.elephantsql.com:5432/birylwwg

PW is

X6EM3Al9Jhqzz0w6EaSSx79pa4aXRBZq

Comment: The difference between `Execution time` in the plan output and the measured time in your application code is network overhead (the time it took to send 1661 rows from the Postgres server to your application) and most probably also the time it took your application to process those rows.

Comment: So is that safe to say that consider the same environment, EXPLAIN ANALYSE should be the most correct pointer for query performance? 
I wonder why execution time can be 20ms (optimized) and 2000ms (unoptimized) but the real query execution is in the middle ( 500ms- 1000ms )

Comment: If there is a huge difference between expected <--> actual rowcounts, then your database is missing keys/indexes and/or statistics. Another indication of this is the abundance of hash-joins and sort steps in your query plan. (fix your data model!)